# proper configure .htaccess to avoid this error " The given path contained wildcard characters:"

Tags: perl, apache, .htaccess, wildcard

I need to send some params to my web server witch contain special character like <*> into url.

> Ex: `http://localhost/mypage/X123*12362issasa.`

This special character i will used it for some regexp.

When i try this i get this

> "403 Forbidden You don't have permission to access
>   /mypage/X123*12362issasa. on this server."

apache_error.log contain this line :

> [error] [client 127.0.0.1] (20025)The given path contained wildcard
>   characters: access to /mypage/X123*12362issasa failed

my .htaccess contains this lines:

```
Options +ExecCGI

AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl .py .php

DirectoryIndex mypage.pl

<IfModule mod_charset.c> 
  CharsetRecodeMultipartForms off 
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ mypage.pl?oid=$1
</IfModule>
```

Could someone please help me to proper configure .htaccess file in order to accept this kind of epecial characters ?
Any help will be apreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reasons you shouldn't use an Asterisk in your URL.

1 ) The asterisk *is* allowed in the URL unencoded according to the standard, but according to [RFC 1738 Uniform Resource Locators (URL)](http://www.w3.org/Addressing/rfc1738.txt) it's a special character. So in this case it has a special use.

> RFC 1738            Uniform Resource Locators (URL)             December 1994
>
> Reserved:
>
> Many URL schemes reserve certain characters for a special meaning:
> their appearance in the scheme-specific part of the URL has a
> designated semantics. If the character corresponding to an octet is
> reserved in a scheme, the octet must be encoded.  The characters ";",
> "/", "?", ":", "@", "=" and "&" are the characters which may be
> reserved for special meaning within a scheme. No other characters may
> be reserved within a scheme.
>
> Usually a URL has the same interpretation when an octet is
> represented by a character and when it encoded. However, this is not
> true for reserved characters: encoding a character reserved for a
> particular scheme may change the semantics of a URL.
>
> Thus, only alphanumerics, the special characters "$-_.+!*'(),", and
> reserved characters used for their reserved purposes may be used
> unencoded within a URL.
>
> On the other hand, characters that are not required to be encoded
> (including alphanumerics) may be encoded within the scheme-specific
> part of a URL, as long as they are not being used for a reserved
> purpose.

Additionally in headers it's used for server-only declarations according to [RFC 2068 HTTP 1.1](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2068.txt).

> 9.2 OPTIONS
>
> The OPTIONS method represents a request for information about the
> communication options available on the request/response chain
> identified by the Request-URI. This method allows the client to
> determine the options and/or requirements associated with a resource,
> or the capabilities of a server, without implying a resource action
> or initiating a resource retrieval.
>
> Unless the server's response is an error, the response MUST NOT
> include entity information other than what can be considered as
> communication options (e.g., Allow is appropriate, but Content-Type
> is not). Responses to this method are not cachable.
>
> If the Request-URI is an asterisk ("*"), the OPTIONS request is
> intended to apply to the server as a whole. A 200 response SHOULD
> include any header fields which indicate optional features
> implemented by the server (e.g., Public), including any extensions
> not defined by this specification, in addition to any applicable
> general or response-header fields. As described in section 5.1.2, an
> "OPTIONS *" request can be applied through a proxy by specifying the
> destination server in the Request-URI without any path information.
>
> If the Request-URI is not an asterisk, the OPTIONS request applies
> only to the options that are available when communicating with that
> resource.  A 200 response SHOULD include any header fields which
> indicate optional features implemented by the server and applicable
> to that resource (e.g., Allow), including any extensions not defined
> by this specification, in addition to any applicable general or
> response-header fields. If the OPTIONS request passes through a
> proxy, the proxy MUST edit the response to exclude those options
> which apply to a proxy's capabilities and which are known to be
> unavailable through that proxy.

2 ) It's a reserved character (sub delimiter) as of [RFC 3986 URI Generic Syntax January 2005](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.2) (thanks to @Daxim for pointing this out).

> 2.2. Reserved Characters
>
> URIs include components and subcomponents that are delimited by
> characters in the "reserved" set.  These characters are called
> "reserved" because they may (or may not) be defined as delimiters by
> the generic syntax, by each scheme-specific syntax, or by the
> implementation-specific syntax of a URI's dereferencing algorithm.
> If data for a URI component would conflict with a reserved
> character's purpose as a delimiter, then the conflicting data must be
> percent-encoded before the URI is formed.
>
> reserved    = gen-delims / sub-delims
>
> gen-delims  = ":" / "/" / "?" / "#" / "[" / "]" / "@"
>
> sub-delims  = "!" / "$" / "&" / "'" / "(" / ")"
> / "*" / "+" / "," / ";" / "="
>
> The purpose of reserved characters is to provide a set of
> delimiting    characters that are distinguishable from other data
> within a URI.    URIs that differ in the replacement of a reserved
> character with its    corresponding percent-encoded octet are not
> equivalent.  Percent-    encoding a reserved character, or decoding a
> percent-encoded octet    that corresponds to a reserved character,
> will change how the URI is    interpreted by most applications.  Thus,
> characters in the reserved    set are protected from normalization and
> are therefore safe to be    used by scheme-specific and
> producer-specific algorithms for    delimiting data subcomponents
> within a URI.

3 ) In some of the host operating systems it's used as a wildcard.

Either way you should avoid using unencoded asterisks in your request URI.

Comment: @daxim If you read the link you've provided it's not obsoleted, it's updated. 1738 is the HTML 1.1 standard.

Comment: @daxim I've appended my answer. Thanks.

Comment: @ikegami It's used in Perl Regex as a Wildcard like this `.*` I pulled that from my answer though. It's likely the RFC 3986 part.

Comment: @ikegami You're right, I've updated my answer. It all gets mixed up in my head. I misread the first part of the link I posted and transposed it... "In UNIX (and other operating systems), the asterisk is a sort of wildcard operator. In Perl, you can refer to other variables and so on by using the asterisk operator" I remembered reading that around 2005. When I saw the link I posted it without thinking. My deepest apologies.